# Why we expect a black hole to have an emissivity of 1?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, thermal-radiation

Just wondering: why we expect a black hole to have an emissivity of 1?
Can anyone give some ideas?

Comment: Do you mean [black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) or [black body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body)?

Comment: I mean black hole

Comment: @ThomasFritsch Why would you assume it is a typo?

Comment: We do *not* expect a black hole to have an emissivity or absorptivity of 1. “A black hole, being of finite size, is not a perfect black body; the absorption cross section goes down in a complicated, spin-dependent manner as frequency decreases, especially when the wavelength becomes comparable to the size of the event horizon” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation

Comment: @G.Smith So essentially because finite sized black bodies can't exist at all, obviously a BH is not a perfect black body.  I'm not sure if that really addresses the spirit of the question, because we could just say _nothing real_ is a perfect black body due to finite size not being able to account for every wavelength.

Answer (score 0):

In Classical Thermodynamics emissivity is the same as absorptivity due to the requirement of thermal equilibrium. Since absorptivity is 1, approximately, so is emissivity.

Comment: This is wrong. “A black hole, being of finite size, is not a perfect black body; the absorption cross section goes down in a complicated, spin-dependent manner as frequency decreases, especially when the wavelength becomes comparable to the size of the event horizon.” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation

Comment: Sure, but still it is close to one since the effect is important only for large wavelengths. I have edited the answer to reflect the comment.

Comment: Well, at large enough wavelengths, they fall to *zero*. That is not close to 1! You can’t pretend that long wavelengths don’t matter. The emissivity and absorptivity are *highly frequency dependent*.

Comment: We normally don't have wavelengths close to the size of a typical black hole.

Comment: Radio waves have wavelengths up to 100 km. This is *much larger* than a solar-mass black hole.